# mumps query related to %%

Tags: mumps

What is the meaning of `I $E(R%%,I%%)>1` ? and why using `%%`?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you are talking about Standard MUMPS (not any particular implementation)
the R%% is illegal syntax.  I have seen the non-standard use of % in extensions to MUMPS, such as EsiObjects or InterSystems Cache Object Script, but the use in the question above is actually nonsense in standard MUMPS.

Answer (score 2):

There is no particular significance to %%. Its just part of the variable name and I still don't understand MUMPS community obsession with using % in variable names and making them more obscure.

so the statement means `IF $EXTRACT(R%%,I%%)>1` i.e if the extracted value from the string `R%%` at position `I%%` is greater than 1, do some more obscure stuff.

> $EXTRACT(string,from) extracts a
>   single character in the position
>   specified by from. The from value can
>   be an integer count from the beginning
>   of the string, an asterisk specifying
>   the last character of the string, or
>   an asterisk with a negative integer
>   specifying a count backwards from the
>   end of the string.

Link to documentation: http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_fextract

Comment: what will return if we execute this $EXTRACT(R%%,I%%)>1 statement?